# PDFs made in GIMP - Transparent background comes out red

Tags: gimp, pdf, transparency

I'm trying to make PDF with a transparent background.  It's just a PAID stamp:  i'm using PDFTK to make a receipt from an invoice by overlaying the PDF which just has the stamp graphic over the PDF of the invoice.

The problem i'm having is that the "PAID" PDF keeps either losing the transparency, so it's all white and the white hides all the invoice text, or the transparency comes out red (thus producing just a red doc with the PAID stamp).

What is the best way to produce a PDF with a transparent background?  I have one which works, and one which doesn't, and when I open them both in GIMP the layers and channels seem identical.

thanks

EDIT - to combine them i'm using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) which is a mac/linux command line utility.  This is an automated process, ie is done on demand by our production server when an invoice is paid.  However before I even get to that stage, I have the problem where I save out the PDF with a transparent background, then load it back in, and the background has turned red.

Comment: Hi. Which software are you using to assemble the finished PDF? I just tried making a transparent PDF in GIMP and it works just fine in other software such as Photoshop. Does the software you are using support alpha transparency? What settings are you using to save the stamp PDF? Is the image contained in the PDF vector or raster?  Also why do you need the stamp to be a PDF?  Can't you just use something like a transparent PNG?

Comment: I am using pdftk which is a command line utility.  It can only combine PDFs, not PDFs and PNGs.   I ended up giving up with the one made in gimp and doing an approach where I use ImageMagick convert to make the stamp PDF from a PNG every time, then using pdftk to combine them, which works.